# How to search a String value in Sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on a project and I have little understanding in sqlite. I am working on android application for searching a name from sqlite local database.
I want to grap a text (name) from the editText box and then do query in sqlite.
I found out how to grap a text from the editText box -

```
EditText txtname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
String name      =  txtname.getText().toString();
```

From my research, I found this is how you do query in sqlite -

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '%XXXX%';
```

Since, I don't know what user will search in the editText box.

How can I do query that user entered in the editText box to the sqlite database.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking but I guess it's how to pass the `name` to the query.

Use `SQLiteDatabase.query()` with selection arguments, for example

```
db.query("Customers", null, "City LIKE ?", new String[] { "%" + name + "%" }, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Could you please collaborate more with using SQLiteDatabase.query() in this scenario.